# Why does this dplyr::select(where( statement not work (must return a boolean)?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am using this select statement

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(
    where(
      function(x) is.numeric(x) | mean(x) > 10
    )
  )
```

However, I get the error saying:

```
Error in `dplyr::select()`:
! `where()` must be used with functions that return `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
Backtrace:
  1. mtcars %>% ...
  3. dplyr:::select.data.frame(...)
  6. tidyselect::eval_select(expr(c(...)), .data)
  7. tidyselect:::eval_select_impl(...)
 16. tidyselect:::vars_select_eval(...)
     ...
 19. tidyselect:::reduce_sels(node, data_mask, context_mask, init = init)
 20. tidyselect:::walk_data_tree(new, data_mask, context_mask)
 21. tidyselect:::as_indices_sel_impl(...)
 23. purrr::map_lgl(data, predicate)
 24. tidyselect .f(.x[[i]], ...)
```

But isn`t the function returning a boolean?

Comment: It works fine for me.  Please check your `packageVersion('dplyr')`

Comment: hm, mine it 1.0.8

Comment: I also use `1.0.8`.  Maybe you have loaded other packages and `select` got masked.  Use `dplyr::select` explicitly

Comment: no, thats not the reason. Just tried it. And also tried it with version 1.09

Comment: for some strange reason its working if I run it in the terminal...

Comment: Try on a fresh Rstudio session

Comment: When you load the packages, did you only loaded `library(dplyr)` or is it `library(tidyverse)`?

Comment: now it works in a fresh rstudio session;) thanks a lot!:)

Comment: now it doesn't again haha 
Anyways, I'll figure it out;) thanks!

Comment: I  have `packageVersion('tidyselect')#
[1] ‘1.1.2’`

Comment: i do have the same version